# What's the difference between String[] and [String] in typescript ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

What's the difference between String[] and [String] in typescript ? 
What is the best option to choose between the two ?

Comment: the second is a "tuple", meaning `let a:[String]` would therefore expect `a` to be an array, whose first index is of the String type. i.e., `let a:[string,number]` would expect the first element of the `a` array to be a string, and the second to be a number. [Gotten from this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)

Comment: On a side note: "Don’t ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, or Object".
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not the same!

**Update:** Since [TypeScript 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html) this is not entirely correct anymore (see below for additions):

- `string[]` says the variable is an array with values of type string (it can be of any size, even empty).
- `[string]` says the variable is an array of size >= 1 and the first entry is a string

  - since 2.7: size === 1
- the `[type]` syntax can be extended, like `[type1,type2,type3,typeN]` and then requires the array to have a size of at least N and the first N types are as specified, while the following types are the union of those types.

Some different examples that illustrate this issue:

```
const testA: string[] = []; // good
const testB: [string] = []; // Error, array must have a string at position 0
const testC: [string, number] = ["a", 0]; // good
const testC1 = testC[0]; // testC1 is detected to be string
const testC2 = testC[1]; // testC2 is detected to be number

const testD: [string, number] = ["a", 0, "1"]; // good before 2.7, bad afterwards
const testD1 = testD[2]; // testD1 is detected to be string | number
const testE: [string, number] = ["a", 0, 1]; // good before 2.7, bad afterwards
const testE1 = testE[2]; // testE1 is detected to be string | number
const testF: [string, number] = ["a", 0, null]; // Error, null is not of type string|number
```

**Since TypeScript 2.7**

[The size is by default fixed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html). So if you want [string] to allow more than one entry, you need to specify in a very ugly way:

```
interface MinimumStrTuple extends Array<number | string> {
    0: string;
}
```

Comment: You're right!  [string] is actually known as a tuple type.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Returning to the basics , what is TypeScript ? 
TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to javascript in the end

Javascript doesn't support types if you write code like this

```
// its OK to write code like 
let str = 'sfafsa' ;
str = true ;
```

but TypeScript helps you write a typed code and you'll get error before compiling if you're trying to assign a value that is not the type  of the variable 
if you try the differnet syntax for writing array

**They are the same** why ? because typescript will compile them the same 
for example

```
let str: String[] = ['ge', 'gege', 'egeg'];
let str2: [String] = ['ge', 'gege', 'egeg'];
```

will compilied to

```
var str = ['ge', 'gege', 'egeg'];
var str2 = ['ge', 'gege', 'egeg'];
```

so they compiled to the same code so use whatever you'll find better for you and I recommend to use the same convention for your code base 
BTW :- I use this syntax `let str: String[]=[]`;

Note :- If you use this syntax **[String]** that means you should have an array that has at least one String >> so in this case empty array will give you error

> thanks @Lusito for paying attention to complete the answer .

Comment: If you look at my examples well , you'll see that I mean here that the 2 arrays should contain string and , here I am not talking about empty arrays I am talking about strings only not other types

Comment: Just because both can be used in this specific example does not mean that they are the same. You may not be talking about other scenarios in your answer, but the question was about the difference between the two language constructs. So, while your answer does work and you can use it like that, it is wrong in respect to the original question.